# fill in the values of an array using the array.map

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-map

I'm trying to understand this code that uses `Array.map()`

```
var char_set = Array.apply(null, Array(256)).map(Boolean.prototype.valueOf, false);
```

The above code is creating an array with indexes from `0-255` and the each value is set to `false`

Could someone explain how this array is being created with this `map` method. The syntax of `map` method is

```
arr.map(callback[, thisArg])
```

In my case is `thisArg` set to `false`?

Comment: It would be easier to do `new Array(256).fill(false)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Array.apply(null, Array(256))` : will create array of 256 elements with value undefined in all the elements

`map(…)` : is used to initialize all values to false

The first argument in `map` takes a callback function; `Boolean.prototype.valueOf` is a function that will act as a callback.

`true.valueOf()` returns `true` but it has to be invoked with thisArg.
    |
     ---------- true is thisArg

`false.valueOf()` returns `false` but it has to be invoked with thisArg.
    |
     ---------- false is thisArg

when `map(Boolean.prototype.valueOf, false)` is invoked for each element in an array it will pass `false` as `this` to `Boolean.prototype.valueOf` method. It is as good as invoking `false.valueOf()` hence it always returns `false`.

Thus `map(Boolean.prototype.valueOf, false)` is equivalent to:
`map(function(item){ return false.valueOf() });`